# Webpack with postcss-loader not recognizing precss

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, postcss

I have a React app (ejected from create-react-app) and I'm trying to add PostCSS to the Webpack configuration.

Here's my (shortened) webpack.config.js:

```
...
const postCSSConfig = require('./postcss.config');

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    postcss: function () {
      return postCSSConfig;
    },
...
```

Here's my postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('precss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

My file structure is:

```
project/
  src/
    assets/
    components/
    styles/
    views/
    index.js
  package.json
  postcss.config.js
  webpack.config.js
```

When I try to make my CSS include some of the features in PreCSS (like nesting and variables, for example), it breaks the styling and doesn't work.  But, the `autoprefixer` works.  I've run `npm install` for PreCSS and tried rearranging things, but still no luck.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error when it breaks?

Comment: @AdamWolski there is no error, the CSS just doesn't support the nesting (and other precss things).

Comment: try removing `postcss` field from your configuraion. The plugin should look for the file on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just include your post-css configuration directly into your webpack config ? I had success doing that, I can't really find any documentation regarding postcss.config and how properly write them.

```
module.exports = {
...
  module: {
    loaders: [
     ...
     {
       test: /\.css$/,
       loaders: [
         'style-loader',
         'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
         'postcss-loader'
       ]
     },
     ...
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [
      require('precss'),
      require('autoprefixer')
    ];
  }
};
```